# R : regular expression for 'not followed by' not working

Tags: regex, r

I needed to retain the words enclosed in brackets and delete the others in the following string.

(a(b(c)d)(e)f)

So what I expected would be (((c))(e)).
To delete a, b, d, f, I tried the 'not followed by' regex.

```
str <- "(a(b(c)d)(e)f)"
gsub("([a-z]+)(?!\\))", "", str) #(sub. anything that isn't followed by a ")" )
```

The message shows my regex in invalid. As I can see, the brackets in the second part of the regex "(?!\))" don't match properly. As for my editor, the first "(" matches with the immediately following ")", which is not meant to be a closure bracket (the one to its right is). I could make out just this error from my regex. Can you please tell me what actually is wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I don't think what you were trying to do would work as you expected even if you had a valid regex.  Note that "d" and "f" ARE followed by a ")".  You may need to resort to multiple gsubs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In two steps, and using [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str1 <- gsub("\\([a-z](?=\\()", "\\(", str, perl=TRUE)
str1
# [1] "(((c)d)(e)f)"
str2 <- gsub("\\)[a-z](?=\\))", "\\)", str1, perl=TRUE)
str2
# [1] "(((c))(e))"
```

Edit: it turns out you can even do it in one:

```
gsub("([\\(\\)])[a-z](?=\\1)", "\\1", str, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "(((c))(e))"
```

Comment: Can someone pl breakdown what the above means?  I could not make the following work: str <- c("hello","hello world")
str_extract(str,"[a-z]*?!\\s*") .   I wanted to capture a string patter with   [a-z]*  that is not followed by a space with   ?!\\s   it did not work.  I was hoping to get hello  and NA in return. Instead I get  NA NA returned.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Dason's comment:

```
st <- "(a(b(c)d)(e)f)"

while(grepl("\\([a-z]+\\(",st)) {
  st <- sub("\\([a-z]+(\\(.+\\))[a-z]+\\)","\\1",st)
}
> st
[1] "(c)(e)"
```

Written on my iPad :-)